# How to process an array (or manually process ng-repeat)?

Tags: angularjs, html

Using: AngularJS v1.3.15

Disclaimer:  I know virtually nothing about angularjs.  But I'm "forced" to use it because its being used in a framework that I am using.

I want to modify some html/angularjs that looks like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="provider in model.externalProviders">
            <a class="pure-button" href="{{provider.href}}">{{provider.text}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I can see what is going on here...  `ng-repeat` causes an iteration on the elements of the `model.externalProviders` collection/array.  It works fine, but I have no control over content/styling individual `<a>` elements depending on the provider.  I would like to change the content/appearance of the `<a>` element depending on type.

The relevant part of the model looks like this:

```
"externalProviders": [
  {
    "type": "Google",
    "text": "Sign-in with Google",
    "href": "https://localhost:44302/external?provider=Google&amp;signin=04e029cf1018403f1757b097fbfb1ecb"
  }
],
```

So I thought maybe there is a way to "select" or "pick" from externalProviders by type...  If that type exists, then render the appropriate markup, e.g.:

```
    <ul>
        <!-- if model.externalProviders has item with type=="Google"... -->
        <li>
            <a class="pure-button button.google" href="<i class="fab fa-google"></i>{{provider.href}}">{{provider.text}}</a>
        </li>
        <!-- if model.externalProviders has item with type=="Facebook"... -->
        <li>
            <a class="pure-button button.facebook" href="<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>{{provider.href}}">{{provider.text}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Not sure what the proper search terms would be so I had trouble finding any info that might solve my problem.  Is something like this possible with AngularJS?  If so, how would I accomplish it?

Comment: Let us know if `ngClass` suits your needs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Looks like that would work if all I was doing was changing the css class (which, is actually all I'm doing in the example).  Luckily font awesome has icons for all of the external identity providers I an using, so I have no need to not include the icon in certain cases.  And actually, looks like I don't even need to use ngClass (see my answer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Major Sam commented, the `ngClass` might work for less simple scenarios, but I don't even need to go that far.  Luckily I have control over the type property and the css, so I can make my type and css selector match the font awesome icon class selector for the icon.  This works:

```
        <li ng-repeat="provider in model.externalProviders">
            <a class="pure-button button-{{provider.type}}" href="{{provider.href}}"><i class="fab fa-{{provider.type}}"></i>{{provider.text}}</a>
        </li>
```

Drawbacks:  Doesn't allow you to change the actual markup (like, e.g., not include the icon if font awesome didn't have one for that provider).

Comment: I know I already mentioned it, but you could use `ngClass` to include an icon (or its fallback, or _not include_) according to your needs, but that would require knowing what you need to include (e.g all the providers and their icons). Just in case you haven't thought of that.